# Can I run LND without ZMQ?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, zeromq

The [documentation for LND](https://docs.lightning.engineering/lightning-network-tools/lnd/lnd.conf) says:

```
; ZMQ socket which sends rawblock and rawtx notifications from bitcoind. By
; default, lnd will attempt to automatically obtain this information, so this
; likely won't need to be set (other than for a remote bitcoind instance).
; bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
; bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
```

Is there a way to turn that default off and not use ZMQ?

Answer (score 3):

According to LND [install guide](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#using-bitcoind), ZMQ is a requirement to run the daemon as long as `bitcoind` is being used as the backend:

> Since lnd uses ZeroMQ to interface with bitcoind, your bitcoind installation must be compiled with ZMQ. Note that if you installed bitcoind from source and ZMQ was not present, then ZMQ support will be disabled, and lnd will quit on a connection refused error. If you installed bitcoind via Homebrew in the past ZMQ may not be included (this has now been fixed in the latest Homebrew recipe for bitcoin)